# imageView in tabHost

Tags: android, imageview, android-tabhost

good morning.

how to I change a imageView into a tab.

this imageView need three states normal img1.png pressed img2.png and selected img3.png.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize a Button instead of an ImageView. Buttons have exactly these 3 states. [Here](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56) you can find a tutorial for that.